# callbacks in browser after socket.io emit

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, callback, socket.io

i am developing a way to get callbacks in the browser page, following a emit to the socketio server.

server code:

```
/** exec php file and retrieve the stdout */
socket.on('php', function(func, uid, data) {
    console.log('php'.green + ' act:' + func + ' uid:' + uid);
    runner.exec("php " + php_[func].exec,
    function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
        if (err == null) {
            socket.emit('php', {uid: uid, o: stdout});
            console.log('emitted');
        } else {
            console.log('err '.red + stdout + ' ' + stderr);
        }
    });
});
```

this code executes a php page and retrieves the output to display or parse in the browser
it receives an id to echo back to the page, so I  can know what function to execute

browser code to execute callbacks:

```
    function log(text) {
        $('.out').append(text + '<br />');
    }
    window.callbacks = [];

    function setcb(c) {
        var max = 0;
        $.each(window.callbacks, function(index) {max = (index > max ? index : max);});
        window.callbacks[max+1] = c;
        return max+1;
    };
    function C(k){return(document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+k+'=([^;]*)')||0)[2]}

    var s = io.connect("http://"+ window.location.host +":8088");
    //s.emit('debug', 'here');
    s.on('getid', function(){
        console.log('getid cookieis: ' + C('igr') );
        s.emit('setid', C('igr'));
    });


    s.emit('php', 'test',
        setcb(
            function () {
                var data = JSON.parse(this);
                log('callback passed' + this);
            }
        ), null
    );

    s.on('php', function(data) {
        //window.callbacks[j.uid].call(j.o);
        log('rec' + JSON.stringify(data));
        //var jsn = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(window.callbacks[data.uid]);
        window.callbacks[data.uid].call(data.o);
        delete window.callbacks[data.uid];
        window.callbacks.splice(data.uid, 1);
        console.log(window.callbacks);
    });
```

this is working, but when I try to make two requests at the same time, it doesn't run like expected, leaving one callback to execute and in the callbacks array.

test code:

```
    s.emit('php', 'test',
        setcb(
            function (data) {log('callback passed' + this);}
        ), null
    );
    s.emit('php', 'test',
        setcb(
            function (data) {log('callback passed' + this);}
        ), null
    );
```

I want to eliminate this error, and for each event received, execute the callback I define.

Comment: you need to emit data, not functions. you also should subscribe before you publish, but that might not be the only issue since the server trip time would likely cover the time spent on the rest of the stack... it's really much simpler than the code you have already, review the socket.io examples. in short, emit()ing should cause your on() callbacks to fire, you don't need to invoke them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way more simple than I've imagined
You can pass by reference the callback.
server side code:

```
/** exec php file and retrieve the stdout */
socket.on('php', function(func, data, callback) {
    console.log('php'.green + ' act:' + func);
    runner.exec("php " + php_[func].exec,
    function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
        if (err == null) { 
            callback(stdout);
            //socket.emit('php', {uid: uid, o: stdout});
            console.log('emitted');
        } else {
            console.log('err '.red + stdout + ' ' + stderr);
        }
    });
});
```

client side code:

```
    function log(text) {
        $('.out').append(text + '<br />');
    }
    function C(k){return(document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+k+'=([^;]*)')||0)[2]}

    var s = io.connect("http://"+ window.location.host +":8088");
    //s.emit('debug', 'here');
    s.on('getid', function(){
        console.log('getid cookieis: ' + C('igr') );
        s.emit('setid', C('igr'));
    });


    s.emit('php', 'test', null,
        function(data) { log('d: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); }
    );
```